# Running a .cpp file on a GPU paperspace machine

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gpu

I have a paperspace account and I loaded a .cpp file I want to run since it will be faster than the machine I am using. I need to use c++11 thus I put this command into the paperspace terminal:

```
g++ -std=c++11 your_file.cpp -o main
```

But I do not get any output it just goes to the next line. I will screenshot what I mean here:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oHRK.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: What issue? The compiler doesn't generate any output on success.

Comment: @duskwuff Yes it does not give me any output.

Comment: That means it's working correctly. The compiler doesn't print anything unless there's an error or warning.

Comment: @duskwuff Thats great but how do I get it to print something?

Comment: By running the program which you've compiled.

Comment: @duskwuff I want to see the output when I run the .cpp file. Do you know how to accomplish that?

Comment: @duskwuff Okay can you show me how to run it?

Comment: Type `./Lesson` an press "enter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you enter in to the terminal only compiles your code and outputs an executable file. 
(The outputted file is usually called 'a.out' but in your case it will be called 'main' as that is what you specified with the -o flag)

In order to run the executable you will have to type: The path to the executable followed by a slash followed by the executables name. For example:

```
/my/cpp/dir/main
```

A quick way to run an executable that is in your current directory is by simply typing:

```
./main
```